# Image Resize with constraint proportion and tranparancy

Tags: php, image-processing, transparency, resize

How do i resize image preserving its dimension ratio proportion and transparancy in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GD library](https://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc/blob/master/system/gd.php) from [MicroMVC](http://micromvc.com). It's the smallest, fastest GD lib out there.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is called [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://www.php.net/function.imagecopyresampled); don't forget to only use true color images for destinations.  Here is a comment which talks specifically about preserving transparency: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#93166 (note the usage of the `imagecolorallocatealpha()` function)